# extracting <h2> title text from html where title text might include newlines

Tags: html, r, text, extract

I have an html file with some `<h2>` tags such as

```
a <- '<section id="sec-standard-stoet-geary" class="level2" data-number="9.4">
      <h2 data-number="9.4" class="anchored" data-anchor-id="sec-standard-stoet-geary">
      <span class="header-section-number">9.4</span> Standardising PISA results</h2>'

b <- '<span class="fu">read_parquet</span>(<span 
     class="st">"&lt;folder&gt;PISA_2015_student_subset.parquet"</span>)</span></code><button 
     title="Copy to Clipboard" class="code-copy-button"><i class="bi"></i></button></pre> 
     </div>
     </div>
     </section><section id="sec-leftjoin" class="level2" data-number="9.3"><h2 data-number="9.3" 
     class="anchored" data-anchor-id="sec-leftjoin">
     <span class="header-section-number">9.3</span> Linking data using <code>left_join</code>
     </h2>
     <p>some text</p>'

c <- paste(a,b,a)
```

I can extract the title of the `a` using:

```
str_extract_all(a, '(?<=(<[/]span>)).*(?=(<[/]h))')[[1]] %>% str_squish()
> [1] "Standardising PISA results"
```

But trying this on `b` returns nothing:

```
str_extract_all(b, '(?<=(<[/]span>)).*(?=(<[/]h))')[[1]] %>% str_squish()
> character(0)
```

and `c` only returns the first and third instance of h2 when it should return all instances:

```
str_extract_all(c, '(?<=(<[/]span>)).*(?=(<[/]h))')[[1]] %>% str_squish()
> [1] "Standardising PISA results" "Standardising PISA results"
```

EDIT: from the comments this appears to be the regex not being able to parse the newline characters.

I've tried enabling single line mode in regex `(?s)` for the parsing, but it's still not working

Comment: the .* in your regex is not matching across multiple lines, and it's stopping at the newline characters within the <code> block.

Comment: Have you tried using an HTML parser instead? [`read_html`](https://xml2.r-lib.org/reference/read_xml.html) seems to be a good fit.

Comment: ah, that seems to fix it, I can remove the `\n`, but how can .* match new lines as well?

Comment: With `(?s)(?<=</span>).*?(?=</h)`

Comment: I tried that, but it seems to overmatch.

Comment: Ok, you must mean the left-hand boundary issue. So, `(?s)(?<=</span>)(?:(?!</span>).)*?(?=</h)`. And this is exactly why you should not use regex parse HTML.

Comment: I think I've learned that lesson now. It's horrible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a helper function that will choose H2 eleements with spans but will ignore the spans

```
library(xml2)
library(stringr)

geth2 <- function(x) {
  temp <- read_html(x) %>% xml_find_all("//h2[span]")
  xml_remove(xml_find_all(temp, ".//span"))
  temp %>% xml_text() %>% str_squish()  
}

geth2(a)
# [1] "Standardising PISA results"
geth2(b)
# [1] "Linking data using left_join"
```

If you wanted to keep the markup inside the H2, this could work

```
geth2 <- function(x) {
  temp <- read_html(x) %>% xml_find_all("//h2[span]")
  xml_remove(xml_find_all(temp, ".//span"))
  temp %>% xml_contents() %>% as.character() %>% str_flatten(" ") %>% str_squish()  
}
geth2(a)
# [1] "Standardising PISA results"
geth2(b)
# [1] "Linking data using <code>left_join</code>"
```

For a version that will work with multiple H2 tags, you can use

```
geth2 <- function(x) {
  temp <- read_html(x) %>% xml_find_all("//h2[span]")
  xml_remove(xml_find_all(temp, ".//span"))
  cleanup <- . %>% xml_contents() %>% as.character() %>% str_flatten(" ") %>% str_squish() 
  sapply(temp, cleanup)
}
geth2(c)
# [1] "Standardising PISA results"
# [2] "Linking data using <code>left_join</code>"
# [3] "Standardising PISA results"
```

Comment: this works for these individual code chunks `a` and `b`  but not for a file that has multiple h2s that match this. Sorry should have made that clearer in the question.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide such an example that can be used for testing along with the desired output

Comment: I've just added `c` as a longer example

Comment: @pluke Update with a more vectorized approach

Answer (score 3):

I would use an html parser instead of regex here:

```r
library(rvest)

read_html(a) |> html_elements("h2") |> html_text() |> trimws()
#> [1] "9.4 Standardising PISA results"

read_html(b) |> html_elements("h2") |> html_text() |> trimws()
#> [1] "9.3 Linking data using left_join"
```

Comment: can you keep the code tags?

Also, it's rather fiddly, I only want to capture the h2s where they have a span inside, but not to capture the span text